# Replicate the array number of times in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl

I have array which contains 5 elements `(1,2,3,4,5)`. I want to replicate this a number of times based on the value set in the scalar `$no_of_replication`, e.g. 3.
So that my final array would contain `(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5)`.

Here is what I have tried. It gives me scalar content instead of elements.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my @array  = (1,2,3,4,5); 
print Dumper(\@array);

my $no_of_replication = 3;

my @new_array = @array * $no_of_replication;

print Dumper(\@new_array);
```

My array(`@new_array`) should be like `(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The operator for that is `x` and you need to be careful with the array syntax:

```perl
@new_array = ( @array ) x $no_of_replication;
```

Found the solution here:
[Multiplying strings and lists in perl via Archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20210515101949/http://www.digitage.co.uk/digitage/library/perl/multiplying-strings-and-lists-in-perl)